# Help in finding curve equation.

Tags: conic-sections, elliptic-curves

What I have is length of the bottom line $L$ and area under parabolic curve $S$. How can I find this parabolic curve equation, depending on area under it? The following picture illustrates the problem.

[image]

Comment: You should take into account that since you didn't provide the origin, equation is not unique with respect to vertical and horizontal translation.

Comment: I edited the tags. The question certainly has nothing to do with elliptic curves, and I'm fairly certain that it has nothing to do with integral equations either. Do roll back, if you **know** otherwise :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assume your equation is $y = ax^2$. Compute the area $S$ through integration to find the area under the curve from $x \in [0,L/2]$. You should be able to find $a$ in terms of $L,S$.